# What seems to be a correct regex doesn't work in replace function

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to match three consecutive dots (".") followed optionally by a space.

My idea was the following:

```
\.\.\.\s?
```

[Tested it here](http://regex101.com/r/rK6aY2) and seems to do exactly as expected.

But then when I try to use it in the replace function with javascript it doesn't seem to work, it's quite weird unless I'm missing something silly:

```
replace("\.\.\.\s?", "")
```

Doesn't work, see [live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/c8Bn8/).

What am I missing?

Comment: `new RegeExp` or use a regexp literal. `replace(new RegExp("\\.\\.\\.\\s?"), "")` or `replace(/\.\.\.\s?/, "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex shouldn't be in quotes.  Try...

```
mystr.replace(/\.\.\.\s?/, "")
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8Bn8/8/)

Answer (score 3):

this should work `$('div').text("... hi".replace(/\.\.\.\s?/, ""));`

`String.replace()` takes either a string or a regular expression as the first argument. If it is a string then it is searched for verbatim. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of `String.replace` must be a RegExp object, not String. Change it to:

```
$('div').text("... hi".replace(/\.\.\.\s?/, ""));
```

Or,

```
$('div').text("... hi".replace(new RegExp("\\.\\.\\.\\s?"), ""));
```

Comment: I made a typo and edited it. Or is it something else?

Comment: Take a look at my comment under the question.

Comment: You are nearly there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').text("... hi".replace(/\.{3}/gi, ""));
```

Slightly optimized regular expression.